# Change List View Image on Click In Android

Tags: android, listview

I have images in Listview and I want to change them when I click on them.

How would I do this?

Comment: hi Dennis i am also facing same problem can u pls provide  me the solution for the same ..i would be greatly thanfull of you i am not getting any appropriate ans . on stackoverflow pls help me...emailid:saurabh26213@gmail.com

Comment: @saurabh have u tried the below example on the link given

Comment: actually i have 4 rows in my list view and when i click on list view then i want to change the image of that list view and each row have diffrent-2 images on list click event .so can u pls share me your idea for doing that v v thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use onItemClickListener or  you can  extend ListActivity and override onListItemClick()